# Use of Pop_front() in C++

Tags: c++

I have the small function below (some of you may ask me to put more code but i can't for multiple reasons). I called the `pop_front()` function as you can see but i was told by the compiler that there was no suitable constructor to convert `void` to a `shared_ptr<A>`. However when i removed the parentheses (`pop_front`) the error when away. What is that? `queue` is of type `deque`. Sorry if i didn't provide more code.

```
std::shared_ptr<A> getSS() {

        return queue.pop_front();

    }
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/eWSxgA)

Comment: Re "the error went away", you would need to provide a complete example. Voting to close as lacking example.

Comment: Wow people are really mad. All i wanted to know was if they was a difference people keep down voting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, please read the documentation of queue:http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue about the container.

What the compiler tells you is rather straight forward: the pop_front（） function does not returns the value of the front element. It simply removes it from the container. To access the element at front, you need to use the access function `front()`.

Without further information, I can't judge why your compiler does not complain after you removes the parentheses. I'm guessing that the reason is that your shared pointer with type A is somehow compatible to a function pointer, as that's what you are returning.

Comment: My problem was actually conversion, i had to downcast my return to match my return type. I have more that 10 classes related to each  other thats why i couldn't put more codes

Comment: @bobby I have no way to know what you are trying to achieve, but it is for sure that `return queue.pop_front` is returning a function pointer.

Comment: What i needed was actually the `front()` :D (i forgot that `pop_front()` only remove but not return THANKS)

Answer (score 2):

Remember you use parenthesis to call a method or function, without them you get the method/function address.

When you return `queue.pop_front` you are returning the method's address, not calling it, so you can construct a shared_ptr of it. But when you actually call `pop_front()` you get a void (as pop_front returns void), and... you can't make a shared_ptr from void.

probably you want:

```
... {
    A result = queue.front();
    queue.pop_front();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deque actually stands for double ended queue. So, You can push in it from both end and also pop from it from both end.

The name of inserting functions are: `push_front()` and `push_back()`

and the name of removing functions are: `pop_front()` and `pop_back()`

and the name of accessing functions are: `front()` and `back()`

Note that, inserting and removing functions returns nothing. To access from any end, you have to use accessing functions.

You can see the reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/).

See the example below to be more clear:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<deque>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    deque<int>dq;

    dq.push_front(23);

    cout<<dq.front()<<" "<<dq.back()<<endl;

    dq.push_back(33);

    cout<<dq.front()<<" "<<dq.back()<<endl;

    dq.push_front(43);

    cout<<dq.front()<<" "<<dq.back()<<endl;

    dq.pop_front();

    cout<<dq.front()<<" "<<dq.back()<<endl;

    dq.pop_front();

    cout<<dq.front()<<" "<<dq.back()<<endl;

    dq.pop_back();


    return 0;
}
```